# How to remove dependency definitions from a Make target?

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I'm working on a large project (~3x10^6 lines of code) that builds with nested Makefiles.  I have a file (`subdirs.mk`) which adds some convenience rules for operating on all subdirectories (possibly in parallel).  It includes these rules:

```
$(SUBDIRS_INCLUDES):
$(MAKE) -C $(patsubst %-includes,%,$@) includes

SUBDIRS_INCLUDES := $(patsubst %,%-includes,$(SUBDIRS))

includes: $(SUBDIRS_INCLUDES)
```

It also provides similar rules for `install`, `clean`, `test`, etc.

In one of my upper level Makefiles, I have this code:

```
SUBDIRS = dir1 dir2 dir3
include $(BUILD_TOOLS)/subdirs.mk

includes: $(BUILD_DIR)/version.h
```

I would like the `includes` target in this one case to *only* make $(BUILD_DIR)/version.h, skipping running includes in all the sub-directories.  However, I still want to use subdirs.mk, because it provides other useful functions (the aforementioned `test` and `install` targets).

**Is there a way to clear the dependencies from the `includes` target?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different name besides `includes` for one of the two targets. Make has no notion of 'subtracting' or 'removing' dependencies.

Comment: Makes sense.  Of course, I'm sure the rationale for using user-facing names for these targets was so that files which use them wouldn't have to define anything other than SUBDIRS.  I think I'll probably do something like this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Irix, the Unix variant from Silicon Graphics (SGI), solved this problem by providing a variable in the equivalent of your subdirs.mk file that prefaced all of the included rules.  You then set this prefix in all the children makefiles before you include subdirs.mk.

While it's a lot to absorb, these files: [commondefs](http://linuxsociety.org/pub/test/opengl/docs/man/usr/include/make/commondefs), and [commonrules](http://linuxsociety.org/pub/test/opengl/docs/man/usr/include/make/commonrules) provide the solution you're looking for.

Comment: You noted that this is available on Irix. Is it also available on other platforms? (We also build on Linux, Mac, and Windows).

Comment: The links I provided are from an open-source project, so I imagine you could grab the files integrate them into any make-based system with little modification, if that's what you were asking.